# PHP performance: Memory-intensive variable

Tags: php, performance, memory

Supposing a multidimensional associative array that, when printed as text with `print_r()`, creates a 470 KiB file. Is it reasonable to assume that the variable in question takes up half a MiB of server memory per instance if it is different for each user? Therefore if 1000 users hit the server at the same time almost half a GiB of memory will be consumed?

Thanks.

Comment: WTF was “vim” tag doing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an excellent article on this topic at IBM:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-v521/

UPDATE

The original page was taken down, for now the JP version is still there https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/jp/opensource/library/os-php-v521/

Basic takeaways form it are that you can use `memory_get_usage()` to check how much memory your script currently occupies:

```
// This is only an example, the numbers below will differ depending on your system
echo memory_get_usage () "\ n";. // 36640
$ A = str_repeat ( "Hello", 4242);
echo memory_get_usage () "\ n";. // 57960
unset ($ a);
echo memory_get_usage () "\ n";. // 36744
```

Also, you can check the peak memory usage of your script with `memory_get_peak_usage()`.

As an answer to your questions: `print_r()` is a representation of data which is bloated with text and formatting. The occupied memory itself will be less than the number of characters of `print_r()`. How much depends on the data. You should check it like in the example above.

Whatever result you get, it will be for each user executing the script, so yes - if 1000 users are requesting it at the same time, you will need that memory.

Comment: tl;dr: run `memory_get_usage()`, create your array, then run `memory_get_usage()` again, and subtract.

Comment: Looks like you also should [pass `true` to `memory_get_usage`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2651592/825789).

Comment: The JP version is still live, chrome translates it pretty good https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/jp/opensource/library/os-php-v521/
I'll put the main information into the article