# Print out all variables except one

Tags: php, debugging

In PHP, I get a dump of all variables like so:

```
var_dump(get_defined_vars());
```

However, in one particular application [one of the variables is huge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201431/php-performance-memory-intensive-variable) and I would really like to avoid printing it out. I could foreach over the `get_defined_vars()` array to create a new array and blacklist the problematic variable, but if there is a better way then I would love to know about it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why create the new array, and instead loop through the result of `get_defined_vars()` and not `var_dump` the particular variable in question?

Comment: @Jack: I did not want to run a whole bunch of var_dump()s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var_dump(array_diff_key(get_defined_vars(), array_flip(array('unwantedVar'))));
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a terrific solution!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, could you just unset the var and var_dump() ?

```
unset($bigChuckNorrisVar);
var_dump(get_defined_vars());
```

Granted you might need to use that variable down your program after that, but that's a quick way to debug.

Comment: Thanks, Nifty, but I do need the $bigChuckNorrisVar further down the line! I just don't care what's in it for the purpose of this particular debug.