# Seeking memleaks in php

Tags: php, memory-leaks

i seeking a memleak in a very long running php cli script.
I've tried it with xhprof and xdebug.

Both sum the memory usage up on the entire run and neglect unset()

Ideal would be something where I can step through code or even places in my code at some points a function to store a memory map.
In the memory map i need to see how mutch memory which class or methode use.
To find caches that are growing to big or find variables that wont unset.

Because the script do ~300 jobs and should free up its memmory after each job, but it dont free up everything.

Comment: 1) how do you *know* there's a leak? 2) http://stackoverflow.com/a/2651592/650405 3) what's your question?

Comment: The php version is independent. Currently 5.4.9. But will install what ever is required. I know that there is a leak, because if it works if i process 100 Job at ones, but with 300 i got mem limit exceedet. My Question is: What is the best way to find the leak and i explained hat would be the best way.

Comment: His question is how he can get the usage per class, real_usage only counts the current summary but he need it splitted by each class or class + method like walltime within xhprof. And why he knows he has a leak? Maybe because he encountered that the memory is to big for his data?